# Java Map Lambda Exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a List of Maps with certain keys that map to String values.

Something like `List<Map<String,String>> aMapList;`

**Objective** : Stream over this List of maps and collect values of a single key in all Maps.

How I'm doing this ->

```
key = "somekey";
aMapList.stream().map(a -> a.get(key)).collect(Collectors.averagingInt());
```

**The Problem:** 
I get exceptions **due to** a.get(key) if there is no such key! because averaging this will give a null. How do I check or make lambda ignore any such maps and move on.

I do know that I can add a filter on `a -> a.contains(key)` and then proceed. 
Edit : I can also add more filters or simple check multiple conditions on one filter.
**Possible Solution:**

```
    aMapList.stream().filter(a -> a.contains(key)).
         map(a -> a.get(key)).collect(Collectors.averagingInt());
```

Can this be made prettier?  **Instead of halting the operation, simply skip over them?**
Is there some more generic way to skip over exceptions or nulls. 
For eg. We can expand the lambda and put a try-catch block, but I still need to return something, what if I wish to do an equivalent of "continue".

Eg.

```
(a -> {return a.get(key) }).
```

Can be expanded to -->

```
(a -> {try{return a.get(key)} 
catch(Exception e){return null} }).
```

The above still returns a null, instead of just skipping over.

I'm selecting the best answer for giving two options, But I do not find any of them prettier. Chaining filters seems to be the solution to this.

Comment: Why do you get exceptions? Shouldn't you get null?

Comment: I know one solution. I'm just asking if I can do this in a shorter way.  Too many filters look ugly and make it confusing.

Comment: @cricket_007, because future operations will throw exception. I will get null, but then it will break later and throw the exception.

Comment: Then you'll need to filter the null at some point or ignore them in a map. Basically, there doesn't seem to be a "simpler" way than what you have

Comment: According to @DannyChen, `contains(key)` returning true does not guarantee that `get(key)` will return a none-null-value. For some `Map` implementation you can put null values.

Comment: @LukeLee, agreed. I was thinking up ways to ignore these particular elements of the list. If there is an exception it usually breaks the whole thing. I wish there was some way to simple step to the next element and avoid the erring element.

I can add another filter on null and be done with it. Makes it uglier.

Comment: So you want to ignore exceptions while processing the stream. I should say the example does not show the need because there's no exception thrown.

Comment: @LukeLee, yes and no. More like figuring out if there are better way to add conditions to lambda instead of just filter(). In a simple loop iteration I can do a "if() and continue or try(), catch(){ignore}" and skip the loop. I do not see such a thing in lambda, well not precisely. Example is lacking I will add some more. Although the statement did say so.

Comment: Added an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about wrapping the result with `Optional`:

```
List<Optional<String>> values = aMapList.stream()
            .map(a -> Optional.ofNullable(a.get(key)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Later code will know to expect possible empty elements.

---

The solution you propose has a potential bug for maps that allow `null` values. For example:

```
Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
aMap.put("somekey", null);

aMapList.add(aMap);

aMapList.straem()
    .filter(a -> a.contains("somekey")) // true returned for contains
    .map(a -> a.get("somekey")) // null returned for get
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I forgot to add that in the filter I can also filter on null values. Sorry about that. I mean, I can filter out any number of things by chaining filters and thus filter out null's too. I was wondering if there was a way of doing something like "try{}, catch{ignore}". Where any such cases are ignored and we move onto the list.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Map documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-), and on your comment under your question, you're not actually getting an exception from `a.get(key)`. Rather, that expression produces a null value, and you're having problems later when you run into these null values. So simply filtering out these null values right away should work just fine:

```
aMapList.stream()
    .map(a -> a.get(key))
    .filter(v -> v != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is prettier, simpler, and performs better than the workaround in your question.

I should mention that I usually prefer the `Optional<>` type when dealing with null values, but this filtering approach works better in this case since you specifically said you wanted to ignore elements where the key doesn't exist in a map list.

Comment: Should be `v != null`.

Comment: @LukeLee `v != null` also has a potential bug when the map has a key with `null` value.

Comment: Currently I am more worried about not getting the correct result for common cases.

Comment: @LukeLee: Right. Derrr. :-) @Danny Chen, I'm assuming the OP has already checked `key` for a null value outside of this statement.

Comment: yes. That will work. My actual lambda is a bit larger than this and I'm doing some more things like count() later. I did not write it here because it served no purpose.

Comment: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` is more idiomatic, though probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I could come up with was:

```
aMapList.stream()
        .filter(map -> map.containsKey(key))
        .map(map -> map.get(key))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By formatting the lambda in this fashion, it is easier to see the distinct steps that the code processes.

Comment: I already suggested this as a possible solution. What I'm trying to ask is if there is some way for my lambda to continue working even if there is some exception.

Comment: I am proposing formatting that makes the lambda easier to read and understand. I think this lambda (which as you say is basically the same as yours) is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although I reckon this is not exactly a prettier approach, you could do:

```
aMapList.stream().map(a -> a.containsKey(key) ? a.get(key) : null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `a.get(key)` returns null, so checking if it contains seems pointless

Comment: besides what cricket said, I would rather add another filter :)